# Android application crashes on launch for LinearLayout view with b

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I am trying to create a LinearLayout view with a AddButton and a List view. I have pasted the code below. But as soon as the application launches, It exits with message saying, "Application has stopped unexpectedly". Any clue where I am wrong?

Purpose:
Create a list view with add button at top. The add button will be static and list view scrollable. The add Button is for adding element to List View.

```
|__Button_|
|         |
|List View|
|         |

public class SimpleListActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        LinearLayout mainLayout;
        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
         mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


        int lHeight= LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        int lWidth = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        //------------------------

        Button BtnAdd = new Button(this);
        BtnAdd.setWidth(60);
        BtnAdd.setHeight(60);
        BtnAdd.setFocusable(true);
//        BtnAdd.setId(idBtnNext);
        BtnAdd.setText("Add Hosts");
        mainLayout.addView(BtnAdd, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight,lWidth));

        String[] mStrings = new String[]{"Android", "Google", "Eclipse"};
        // Create an ArrayAdapter, that will actually make the Strings above appear in the ListView
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStrings));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        //------------------------

        mainLayout.addView(lv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight,lWidth));

        setContentView(mainLayout);

         lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { ....... 

      }
```

}

My Manifest file looks like below.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SimpleListActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".Page1"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Page2"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Page3"></activity>

    </application>
```

Comment: Launch your application in the emulator, and take a look at the LogCat *(In Eclipse : Window > Show View > Other ... > Android > LogCat)*. When your application crashes, the stacktrace should be displayed in LogCat.

Comment: I think this is because you're calling `ListView lv = getListView();` BEFORE `setContentView(mainLayout);`. However the LogCat output would allow to say this for sure.

Comment: I agree with @Pascal MARTIN as well.  If you are going to get anywhere with Android programming you absolutely have to get used to looking at the LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take the default ListActivity's ListView (ie from getListView()) and add it to another layout.  You will get an exception (view already has a parent).  If you want to have a custom layout for the ListActivity you need to provide a new ListView with the correct ID.

change

```
 ListView lv = getListView();
```

to

```
 ListView lv = new ListView(this);
 lv.setId(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Thanks slund!! It worked, Hats off you nailed the issue without stack trace.